# What is wrong in my implementation of nonce for a inline-js with csp and flask?

Tags: javascript, flask, nonce

I have implemented a nonce for a csp inline js. Struggling with finding why it doesn't work. When accessing a page get this error:

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://loca.../script.js ("script-src").
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline ("script-src").
```

Implempleted to flask:
// Inside  timer.py file implemented a function to create nonce.

```
def GetCspNonce():
  """Returns a random nonce."""
  NONCE_LENGTH = 16
  return base64.b64encode(os.urandom(NONCE_LENGTH))

nonce = GetCspNonce()

function to redirect to a template:
return render_template('base/timer.html', timer= timer, nonce=nonce)
```

// Added to init.py csp nonce.

```
def create_app():
    # create and configure the app
....

    csp = {
        'default-src': ['\'self\''],
        'script-src': ['https://www.goog....], 'nonce-{nonce}'],...
```

//timer.html

```
<td> 
    <p> ...</p>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/text/script.js" nonce="{nonce}"></script>

            </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are passing the same nonce in the policy and in the template? Also, shouldn't you use an f-string here `'nonce-{nonce}'`?